# Render a new component on the same page

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a form component, and upon filling this form (click submit button), I would like to render a new component in place of the form, on the same page, with some comment like "congratulations for filling the form" for instance.

I am not sure what is the right way to achieve this. I am not sure it is right to do a conditional rendering here.

Also, should this be done on the page where I render the form component, or in an action creator ?

Thank you for your kind help !

Comment: It's fine to use conditional rendering for that since the state is designed for this use case anyways.

Comment: yep, it works well that way with a conditional rendering. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a sample code of how to do it:

```
export var LoginBox = React.createClass({

  getInitialState(){
    return{
      registered:false
    }
  },
  Register(){
    //submit registration form and change form to login form
    ...
    this.setState({registered : true});
  },
  login(){
    // submit login form here
  },
  loginForm(){
      var{registered} = this.state;
      if(registered){// your registeration form
          return(
            <form onSubmit={this.Register}>
              <div><input ref="number" type="tel"/></div>
              <button type="submit">register</button>
            </form>
          );
        }else{
          return (// your login form
            <form onSubmit={this.login}>
              <div><input type="number" ref="activationCode"/></div>
              <button type="submit">login</button>
            </form>
          );
        }
      }
  },
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="loginBox">
          {loginForm()}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

It is a sample code. First, you need to initialize a state for default form. Then, on form submit change the state in order to change form on your view.

I hope it helps you to understand it.